# Может ли вектор быть типом данных функции?

Tags: c++, функции

если да, то как правильно прописать return?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под *типом данных функции*? В параметре и в возвращаемом значении функции может быть. А вообще, почему бы не попробовать написать и проверить, работает или нет? Если пробовали, но не получилось, то приведите ваши попытки

Comment: Кстати, не забывайте помечать подошедшие вам ответы с помощью галочки слева от него. Вам правильно ответили уже на 3 вопроса, а вы ни одного не приняли https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Да, может.
2. Как обычно :) - как для любого другого типа. Ну, например:

   ```
    vector<int> func()
    {
        vector<int> v;

        ...

        return v;
    }
   ```